# mysqli_real_escape_string is not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have looked all over the web, checked the php syntax but I can't understand why this code is not working.

```
  // Create connection
  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","task_user","task","tasks");

  // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "No se puede conectar a la base de datos: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  else{
    //Verificación de la información de logeo
    $username = $_POST["user"];
    $username = stripslashes($username);
    $password = $_POST["passwd"];    
    $username = $mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username);
    //$password = $mysqli_real_escape_string($password);
    //$sqlquery = "SELECT username,password FROM users WHERE username ='$username' AND password='$password'";
  }


  echo '<script type = "text/javascript"> restoreValues("' . $_POST["user"] . '","' .  $_POST["passwd"] . '"); </script>';
  echo "ALL OK";
```

If I comment the mysqli_real_escape_string then it works (ALL OK is printed), if I don't it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong??

Comment: The function's name is `mysqli_real_escape_string`, not `$mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: This is where syntax highlighting really comes in handy (and knowing which colours mean what) -_-

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't store passwords directly in the data base, but rather in a hashed way.

Comment: Use bind variables, then you wouldn't need to use mysqli_real_escape_string (or stripslashes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using `$` sign before function `mysqli_real_escape_string`

make it

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username);
```

instead of

```
$username = $mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username);
            ^ remove this
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm an idiot. Been staring at the code too long and did not notice the obvious. Thank you. Wonder why any of the syntax checkers online did not get that, though.....

Answer (score 1):

You have a $ before mysql_real_escap_string, which is wrong. If you remove the $, it should work. Your version would call a function with the name defined in the variable $mysqli_real_escape_string (which does not exist in your case).